# How to load image during show hide div?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to display a image when I am going to click for hiding a div.Everything works fine but I want to alert a message and load a image before show div.What to do?My js and html code are give below :

```
<h3><a class='show'> (Show/Hide) </a></h3> 
<div id="show"></div>
```

and my js code

```
jQuery(document).ready(function()
{
  $("a.show").click(function(e) {
  // alert("Hi");
    $('#check').animate({ opacity: "toggle" });
    e.stopPropagation();
  });
});
```

I want to add a alert message and a loading image named loading.gif.Any idea?

Comment: What is `$('#check')` ?

Answer (score 1):

You could do it in this order: `FadeOut` , show image and finally `FadeIn`

```
$( "#check" ).fadeOut( "slow", function() {
    // Animation complete
  });
```

http://api.jquery.com/fadeOut/
and
http://api.jquery.com/fadeIn/

Answer (score 1):

jQuery's `animate` is a powerful tool: `show`, `hide`, `fadeIn`, `fadeOut`, `slideUp`, `slideDown`, `fadeTo`, `fadeToggle` (and others I can't put up with) are simply shortcuts to `animate` with specific parameters (very similar to what `$.ajax` is to `$.post`, `$.get`).

Pass a callback to fires off when the animation completes, very much like you'll do it with `show` and `hide`:

```
$("#a").click(function() {
    $("#b")
    .animate({ borderLeftWidth: "15px" }, 1000, "linear", function() {
      //callback -> animation complete
      alert("all done");
    });
});
```

You can even chain multiple call to `animate`. A callback can be bound to each call to `animate`, to make it very sophisticated (and error prone).

```
$("#a").click(function() {
    $("#b")
    .animate({ width: "90%" }, 1000)
    .animate({ fontSize: "24px" }, 1000)
    .animate({ borderLeftWidth: "15px" }, 1000, "linear", function() {
      //callback -> this particular action has been completed
      alert("all done");
    });
});
```

As rule of thumb, make it simple :)

See jQuery documentation for further information: http://api.jquery.com/animate/

Answer (score 0):

```
   jQuery(document).ready(function()
   {
      $("a.show").click(function() {
       $('#check').fadeToggle('slow', function(){
           if($('#check').css('display') == 'none')
           {
            //if #check is hidden
           }
           else
           {
            //if #check is shown
           }
        });
      });
   });
```